# How can I stop JQuery import from breaking existing code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm a beginner developer in Html/Javascript/CSS/Jquery coding
and while working a project, I had to integrate Jquery with previous code.

As soon as I imported Jquery, even simple buttons became styled badly. Jquery worked fine as long as I used its classes to assign styles to objects.

However since the rest of the project is not to change style, I need to know what I'm doing wrong. I've checked the objects for classes, and they have no classes, so it's not a css issue.

I narrowed down the error to the following screenshot, but I still can't figure it out. It seems to be something simple that I missed but I have no idea what it is.

[image]

Ignore the `class="ui-content"` and `class="ui-button-text"`. I was just testing if something would change (nothing changed).

Answer (score 0):

Try to inspect the elements that are styled wrong with your developer tools in the browser. The only styling in your example is in jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css, so that's where I'd be looking. Did you mistakenly delete a link tag to your stylesheet?

Comment: So in the simple example, where the styling is done only through the jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css, why does the button look all wrong? It doesn't have any style associated with it (if class isn't set) so it shouldn't be affected. Why do I need to look into the css if I'm not using it at all?

Comment: It's quite possible the jQuery mobile stylesheet has default styles for elements in it, such as checkboxes and buttons. Is jQuery mobile really necessary for your project?

Comment: Unfortunately, the iframe popup I have implemented breaks if I remove the jquery mobile css or js